# Building a menu system with a PHP class

Tags: php, oop

**UPDATE 2 ::**

This is the output I am getting from the function right now :

```
 <nav>
  <ul> //UL 1
       <ul> //UL 2
        <a href="/">menu link 1</a>

        <li><a href="/login">login</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul><a href="/sub3">sublink3</a></ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>menu link 3</a></li>

        <li>
            <ul>
                <a href="/sub1">sublink1</a>
                    <li><a href="/sub2">sublink2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/path4">menu link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="/path5">menu link 5</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <a href="/sub5a">sublink5a</a>
                <li><a href="/sub5b">sublink5b</a></li>
                <li><a href="/sub5c">sublink5c</a></li>
                <li><a href="/sub5d">sublink5d</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul> //End of UL 2

    <ul></ul> //dont not why this is here?
  </ul> //End of UL 1
</nav>
```

**UPDATE**
Ok I have re-move the construct, and this is how I am  trying to display my menu :

```
     <?php include('./includes/menu.php'); ?>

     <h1>HEADER FILE TITLE TEST</h1>

     <?php  

       $build = new Menu;
       var_dump($build->DisplayMenu());

     ?>
```

---

I mainly only use CakePHP to build sites with, but I am trying to push my PHP skills up to the next level. So I am looking at other frameworks and OOP (which I have never used within PHP before). So I set myself a little task of building a menu system, controllable from a database e.g. titles and path links come form my db.

This works fine when I just built it has a function put all my menu system items within an array and then used a print call to display the menu, then I just called the function on the page I had required the file to.

But I thought that this was not the best way about doing it, so I wanted to make it a class, so I put a class call around my function, and then changed the print call to a return. What I got form the class/function was a NULL answer when I var dumped it. So I did some research, and re-read a lot about how to declare an array within the magic 'construct' function.

But now I am very confused, should this be inside my Menu function or outside? Just by adding the construct function, it started to display 'string(9)' - which I don't know why? Here is my code :

```
 //Menu Include file
 class Menu {
   public $testforme = "dfdfdfdf"; //Just a test to see how to call somedata

   public function DisplayMenu() {
     $DBConn = getConnection(); //Set new database connection
     $SQLMainMenu = "SELECT * FROM menu"; //Get Menu setting from database
   //$MenuBuild[] = NULL; //Open array for menu to save data into

function __construct($MenuBuild = array()) {
 //not sure what to put here??? 

}

try {
    $MenuBuild[] = '<nav><ul>';

    //Foreach loop for all main menu links
    foreach ($DBConn->query($SQLMainMenu) as $MainMenu) {
        $MainMenuID = $MainMenu['id'];
        $MainMenuPath = $MainMenu['linkpath'];
        $MainMenuSublinkCounts = $MainMenu['sublinks'];
        $SQLSubMenu = "SELECT * FROM submenu WHERE menu_id = $MainMenuID";          

        if ($MainMenuPath == 'NULL') {
            $MenuBuild[] =  '<li><a>' .$MainMenu['name'] .'</a>';
        } else {
            $MenuBuild[] =  '<li><a href="'.$MainMenuPath.'">' .$MainMenu['name'] .'</a>';
        }

        if ($MainMenuSublinkCounts >=1) { $MenuBuild[] = '<ul>'; }

        //Foreach loop to build all inner links for menu
        foreach ($DBConn->query($SQLSubMenu) as $SubMenu) {
            $SubLinkMenuIDs = $SubMenu['menu_id'];
            $SubLinkTitles = $SubMenu['name'];
            $SubLinkPaths = $SubMenu['linkpath'];

            if ($SubLinkMenuIDs == $MainMenuID) { 
                                    $MenuBuild[] = '<li><a href="'.$SubLinkPaths.'">'. $SubLinkTitles . '</a></li>'; }
        } //End of inner foreach loop

        if ($MainMenuSublinkCounts >=1) { 
                               $MenuBuild[] = '</ul>'; 
                     }

        $MenuBuild[] = '</li>';

    } //End of foreach loop 

    $MenuBuild[] = '</ul></nav>';

    //Print the Array that holds the menu.
    foreach ($MenuBuild as $MenuKey => $MenuData) { 
                 $MenuSystem = $MenuBuild[$MenuKey]; return $MenuSystem; 
            }

 } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
 }

   } //End of function DisplayMenu

  } //end of class
```

Now I am connection to my db using a PDO, which is working fine, it within a other file that both are included on.

Please let me know of any good help sites and I have read lots of the questions / answers on here.

Also please go easy on me? this is the 1st time I am using OOP PHP.

If of I am not doing something right, with the way I am building the menu please point at any issues with that :).

Thanks Glenn.

Comment: You need to fix your indentation. it LOOKS like your __construct() method is actually a sub-function inside DisplayMenu. That's NOT how constructors work.

Comment: That is what I was thinking! - p.s I am still think that MVC is a better way to build sites with than OOP!

Comment: oop and mvc are two totally different things.

Comment: Yes I know that, I am just saying I think MVC is better to use and cleaner for PHP development of websites than OOP - But I could just be saying that because I am still learning OOP

Comment: I have just move the __construct outside of the DisplayMenu function, still getting a string(9) - what should I declare within the __constuct? that is what I am not sure about?

Comment: __construct is automatically called when you do `$obj = new YourObject()`. it's used to do whatever's necessary to set up the object's internals before use. if you don't need anything like that done, then you don't need a constructor.

Comment: Ok, done some updating to my post!

Comment: Might worth looking at how [KnpMenu](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu) works.

Comment: Thanks for the plugin, but the point was to try and understand basic OOP with PHP, task why I set myself the task of building this menu

Comment: You still don't seem to know the difference between MVC and OOP. for short: `Object Oriented Programming` is how you *program*, MVC is how you organize the procedures from request to response (output). You can do an `MVC` in `procedural` and use `OOP` for some `non-MVCs` and _vice-versa_ and mixed, and...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is for you, but you really need to do some more research before putting something like this up

my approach encapsulates some functionality but it should seem pretty clear where it's headed just by looking at it. Please feel free to make any questions

### *(REREedited)* includes/menu.php

```
<?php
class Menu {
  private $db;
  private $main;
  public function __construct($db=null) {
    $this->db = $db ? $db : getConnection();
    $q = 'SELECT id,name,linkpath,sublinks FROM menu';
    $this->main = $this->db->query($q);
  }
  public function displayMenu() {
    $items = array();
    foreach ($this->main as $row) {
      $path = $row['linkpath'];
      $link = self::link($row['name'],$path==='NULL'?null:$path);
      // if there is a submenu, concatenate to with the "parent" into the same "item"
      if ($row['sublinks'] > 0) $link .= $this->subMenu($row['id']);
      $items[] = $link;
    }
    // returns the whole nav menu.
    return '<nav>'.self::lists(array_filter($items)).'</nav>';
  }
  private function subMenu($id) {
    $q = 'SELECT name,linkpath FROM submenu WHERE menu_id = ';
    $sub = array();
    foreach ($this->db->query($q.$id) as $row) {
      $sub[] = self::link($row['name'],$row['linkpath']);
    }
    return self::lists(array_filter($sub));
  }
  static function link($content, $href) {
    return '<a '.($href?'href="'.$href.'"':'').'>' .$content.'</a>';
  }
  static function lists(array $items) {
    if (!$items) return null;
    return '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>',$items).'</li></ul>';
  }
}
```

### test.php

```
<?php include('./includes/menu.php'); ?>
<h1>HEADER FILE TITLE TEST</h1>
<?php
try {
  $build = new Menu;
  echo $build->displayMenu();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL.$e->getTraceAsString();
}
?>
```

Comment: please give some feedback to see if I can accomodate to your needs for learning

Comment: I understand some of what you are doing here, and thanks for that. But I seem to get an error, within the displayMenu, when the foreach loop is calling $this->menu, comes back with $menu undefined. I should also note here that I am using this within PHP Slim, but I am really only using it has a router, to make my paths nice and clean.

Comment: Ok it sort of works if I remove Slim, so Slim is doing something that the code don't like, I have only just started using it so I play around it to get it working. But it does not build the menu system right, it only displays the main links and not any of the pull down sublinks

Comment: ok, I'll look into it. I don't know anything about Slim but I'll be on the lookout. If there is any error messages post them to me and I'll take a look immediately... I just realized I like to _look_ a lot

Comment: Ok I play around with it a little, I think its a little bit of my problem and what I was and was not doing, but now it displays the follow error when you build a new menu, Missing argument 1 for Menu::__construct(), - there is more to the error, if you want it I can post all of it.

Comment: No, that problem is mine. The constructor function doesn't need an argument, I only left it there to let the constructor have a preexisting db handler or use a default one. You may change the contructor like this `__construct($db=null)`

Comment: Yes that worked, so should you always state that in the construct? it works fine now but still does not build the menu up right, I update my post at the top.

Comment: I edited the class a bit. If there are any problems, I have a feeling your database is not picking up. I had to fix the static functions because it was **wrong**

Comment: I have just updated my post, with what the function is now outputting, its also there, the database has not changed, its just looks - I could be wrong :( - just like the NAV and UL LI tags are not being built right.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42323/discussion-between-hanzo2001-and-glenn-curtis)